Pybliometrics AuthorRetrival() function returning outdated results
I'm trying to retrieve the publications of a list of authors using the AuthorRetrieval() function, and I'm getting outdated results, which I know because when I search up some of the authors on scopus, they have more documents than it shows in my program output.
Here's the code segment that retrieves the documents of an author from Scopus:
For reference, I check to see if the results are updated with the professor Nishant Garg from UIUC, who has 33 documents, with 30 being of type "Journal" (https://www.scopus.com/authid/detail.uri?authorId=55790820200#). However, when I run my code, it says that he has 26 documents of type "Journal", which leads me to believe that the code is giving me outdated results.
I've set the refresh parameter to True in the AuthorRetrieval() function, and I've even tried deleting the local cache ({path}/ENHANCED/{author_id}) before running the code, but it seems to do nothing. Am I missing something?

You're probably not missing anything. Can you update the question please to include what exactly is outdated alongside the author for whom you are searching information? Ideally in code form so that others can easily replicate the issue.

Alright, I added more context to my question. Sorry about that.

You can insert code directly into the question. Makes it easier for people to read. Just have ``` in the line before and after the code for formatting.

Yes you are likely to retrieve old documents. That's because of the way you retrieve the documents. You first use AuthorRetrieval(), and then the method .get_documents(). As the documentation states, this method passes on parameters (via *args and **kwargs) to ScopusSearch(), which performs the actual retrieval of the documents. Here you have use the refresh parameter as well!
from pybliometrics.scopus import AuthorRetrieval

auth_id = 55790820200
au = AuthorRetrieval(auth_id, refresh=5)  # Only refresh every 5 days
docs = au.get_documents(refresh=True)

However, you could simply all of this by using the ScopusSearch() class directly:
from pybliometrics.scopus import ScopusSearch

auth_id = 55790820200
q = f"AU-ID({auth_id})"
s = ScopusSearch(q, refresh=True)
docs = s.results

In both cases I get 33 documents.
